# Class that stores int data for the game

Tags: java, variables, object, constructor

I have a main class "number guess game" but now I need to create an object to get from. I'm trying to add the constructor to the Object class that takes an integer value for the upper limit and uses it to set the upper limit instance variable. Then, generate the number that the user should try to guess and set that instance variable. Finally, initialize the instance variable for the number of guesses to 1.

here is my code

```
public class NumberGame {

//instance variable
    private int upperLimit;
    private int number;
    private int guess;

//constructor
public NumberGame(int upperLimit){

   this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
   this.number = number;
   this.guess = guess;
    }
}
```

unsure if I am on the right path or need to change my variables or add to the constructor. Still learning about instance variables and constructors any help would be greatly appreciated! thank you!

Comment: java or c++?? why not python and R??

Comment: I don't see any C++ here.

Comment: Please don't spam with unrelated language tags. Only use the relevant (which in your case clearly isn't C++).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saying "this.xx" you are referring to the instance variable, when you don't use "this" you are referring to local variables that are getting passed to the constructor. Because you are only passing the upper limit, what you want to do is only set that in the constructor. If the number of guesses always needs to start at "1", you can just initialize it to one in the object class. Lastly,if I'm understanding the question correctly, if you have a method to generate the random number they need to guess, you can call it in your constructor, so you'd end up with something like this:

```
 public class NumberGame {

    //instance variable
        private int upperLimit;
        private int number;
        private int guess = 1; //number of guesses to 1

    //constructor
    public NumberGame(int upperLimit){

           this.upperLimit = upperLimit;
           this.number = generateNumber() //or some method you are using to generate the number for the user to guess
        }
    }
```